# IF, THEN formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table with grade levels of students in column C and the total duration of time earned (sum of D3:F3) in column H.
In column J, I want to calculate a percentage of the total time earned based on the grade level. For example:

If C3="K", then divide H3 by 7.5
If C3="1" or "2", then divide H3 by 11.25
If C3="3", "4", "5" or "6" then divide H3 by 15

Can you assist me with how to put this formula in Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this

`=IF(C3="K", H3/7.5, IF(OR(EQ(C3,"1"),EQ(C3,"2")), (H3/(11.25)), (H3/15)))`

Actually, anything other than "K", "1", or "2" will result in `H3/15`. Modify accordingly. It's because you have not specified what to do when there are values other than what you have listed. So, I have ignored the last condition.

Note: Format `C3` as Text.